# TinyMCE refresh issue

Tags: php, tinymce, refresh

I'm using TinyMCE, witch is working fine for the most part... when the user saves the page redirects to a a php page that extracts the textfield data and processes it, i wont elaborate cause that's no t the issue... the issue is that when it redirects back to the page... the textfield is blank and i can click on it but not see anything, if i type it enters(but i can't see it), this also happens when i go to the address directly, the only way i can see it is to hit the refresh button... i tried a meta refresh to the page... i tried disabling cache... any ideas would be great... thanks in advance

Comment: This problem only occurs in Chrome... and probably other web kit browsers... i tested in firefox and IE no issue there

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this type of error in FF11.tinyMCE creates problem with some latest browsers version.To solve this problem try to get latest version of tinyMCE.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm Afraid this isn't likely the issue as i only first downloaded it 2 days ago... directly from there site, although i may have downloaded the beta by mistake, i will re-download and retry